# How to convert a nested list of Chars to a String Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, char

I have a simple question, although Lists of `Char`s seem equivalent to `String`s, they are not functionally working the same. if I have a nested List of `Char`s, of type `[[Char]]` that I would like to convert to a `[String]`, how would I go about doing this?

When I try to perform a function on the `[[Char]]` and treat it as though it is a string I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type `([String] -> (Int, Int, Board)) -> t'
                with actual type `[[Char]]'
```

When I try to declare that `type String = [[Char]]` I get:

```
Ambiguous occurrence `String'
It could refer to either `Main.String', defined at Testing.hs:19:1
                      or `Prelude.String',
                         imported from `Prelude' at Testing.hs:16:1-14
                         (and originally defined in `GHC.Base')
```

Comment: The are functionally working the same.

Comment: I have tried this, it returns that `String` is `Ambiguous`

Comment: @anon `String` is already defined in the standard library, so when you define another `String` GHC isn't sure which to use (that's what the error here means).

Comment: Ah, so how would I go about clarifying to the compiler which `String` I mean?

Comment: @anon It doesn't really make sense to define `String` as you have it though. A string is conceptually a list of characters, not a list of lists of characters. That also doesn't fit with the first part of your question (if `String` was a synonym for `[[Char]]` then `[String]` would not be `[[Char]]`). With the normal standard library version, `[String]` and `[[Char]]` are already identical and interchangeable with each other.

Comment: @DavidYoug When I try to perform a `[String]` function on the `[[Char]]` I get an error

Comment: @anon This is not the problem. It looks like you are using something as a function which is not a function or passing too many or too few arguments to a function. Could you post the code causing the error? Note that it is trying to match the *entire type* on that first line with the type `[[Char]]`, not just the `[String]` part.

Comment: @DavidYoung Yep, no problem, thanks for your help and patients!

Comment: @DavidYoung Nevermind, I was being silly and placed a function in the wrong place, sorry to waste everyone's time but I appreciate it all the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two types are completely identical, because `String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`. The definition of `String` is

```
type String = [Char]
```

The `type` keyword means it's a type synonym. A type synonym is always interchangeable with the type it is defined to be.

You can see this in GHCi like this (note that Haskell does not allow casting):

```
ghci> let test :: [Char];   test = "abc"
ghci> test :: String
"abc"
ghci> :t (test :: [Char]) :: String
(test :: [Char]) :: String :: String
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to declare that `type String = [[Char]]` I get:
>
> ```
> Ambiguous occurrence `String'
> It could refer to either `Main.String', defined at Testing.hs:19:1
>                       or `Prelude.String',
>                          imported from `Prelude' at Testing.hs:16:1-14
>                          (and originally defined in `GHC.Base')
> ```

You are getting this error because your definition of `String` conflicts with the one already defined in `base` and exported by the `Prelude`. Remove your definition and use the one that already exists instead.